# migrating a Rails 3.2 app to strong parameters and getting this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 3.2. app and am getting an error on the following scope:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  scope :active, -> { where(is_deleted: false) }
```

with this view fragment:

```
<% @location.order('updated_at desc').active.where('menu_event_category_id is ?',nil).each_with_index do |x, idx| %>
```

The error is:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `active' for #<Class:0x0000011da42c20>):
```

Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?.

Comment: What is the class of `@location` here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with strong_parameters. You need to do something like this to use the scope:

```
<% Location.active.order('updated_at desc').where('menu_event_category_id is ?',nil).each_with_index do |x, idx| %>
```

or..

```
<% @location.active.order('updated_at desc').where('menu_event_category_id is ?',nil).each_with_index do |x, idx| %>
```

Further, you should probably set @locations in your controller:

```
@location = Location.active.where('menu_event_category_id is ?',nil)
```

Comment: `@location.active.order('updated_at desc')`  or `@location.order('updated_at desc').active` both should work fine, given we can chain scopes ?

Comment: hmm... so moving after worked correctly. there was something about either the order phrase or the scope as it worked fine without strong params but didn't work with strong params